# Access denied for user 'garage_paraut'

Tags: database-connection, database-project, local-database, database-permissions

I'm trying to connect to my site's database but I get this error,

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
> denied for user 'garage_paraut'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ecf/Table/db_connexion.php:3 Stack trace: #0
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ecf/Table/db_connexion.php(3):
> PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'garage_paraut',
> Object(SensitiveParameterValue)) #1 {main} thrown in
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ecf/Table/db_connexion.php on line 3

although I have given all the privileges to the user. What to do?

Comment: Are you sure the password is correct for the user?

Comment: Good morning, yes it is correct